# Extract value of an element from object instance

Tags: flutter, dart, amplify-flutter

Here is my code to get the current users phone number.

```
  Future<void> getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      AuthUser user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
      print(user.signInDetails);
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      safePrint('Error retrieving current user: ${e.message}');
    }
  }
```

The print statement above which extracts the values of the signInDetails array, does not allow me to go deeper one more level. Here is result if I just print the object instance -

```
CognitoSignInDetailsApiBased {
I/flutter (19338):   "signInType": "apiBased",
I/flutter (19338):   "username": "+14160000000",
I/flutter (19338):   "authFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
I/flutter (19338): }
```

How do I just get the value of username element above.

Comment: What does `AuthUser` look like? More specifically, what is the type of `signInDetails`? Does that type have a field, getter, or method that can return `username` from it?

Comment: @anqit This is what gets printed onto the console if I do print(AuthUser) ```CognitoAuthUser {
                I/flutter (19338):   "userId": "66e708f8-dc6c-4dcf-8521-1a37d7c12305",
                I/flutter (19338):   "username": "66e708f8-dc6c-4dcf-8521-1a37d7c12305",
                I/flutter (19338):   "signInDetails": {
                I/flutter (19338):     "signInType": "apiBased",
                I/flutter (19338):     "username": "+14160000000",
                I/flutter (19338):     "authFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
                I/flutter (19338):   }```

Comment: @anqit this is what the AuthUser class is https://pub.dev/documentation/amplify_core/latest/amplify_core/AuthUser-class.html

Comment: So looking at the doc for `SignInDetails` (https://pub.dev/documentation/amplify_core/latest/amplify_core/SignInDetails-class.html), it looks like there is a `toJson()` method that returns a map. Given that, does `print(user.signInDetails.toJson()['username'])` do what you are looking for?

Comment: @anqit Thanks. Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/amplify_core/latest/amplify_core/AuthUser-class.html) you posted, `AuthUser#signInDetails` returns an instance of `SignInDetails`, documented [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/amplify_core/latest/amplify_core/SignInDetails-class.html). It looks like there isn't an accessor `username`, but there is a `toJson()` method that returns a map. Given that, you should be able to print just the username value via `print(user.signInDetails.toJson()['username'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```dart
Future<void> getCurrentUser() async {
  try {
    AuthUser user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user.signInDetails is CognitoSignInDetailsApiBased) {
      String username = (user.signInDetails as CognitoSignInDetailsApiBased).username;

      print("Username: $username");
    } else {
      print("Unable to retrieve the username.");
    }
  } on AuthException catch (e) {
    safePrint('Error retrieving current user: ${e.message}');
  }
}
```

[CognitoSignInDetailsApiBased class](https://pub.dev/documentation/amplify_auth_cognito_dart/latest/amplify_auth_cognito_dart/CognitoSignInDetailsApiBased-class.html)